# Load jar dynamically

Tags: java, jar, classloader, urlclassloader

In my java application, I read a jar file (packaged with Maven shade plugin) into a bytestream. In the jar there is a entrypoint class defined in `POM.xml`

```
<build>
  ...
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>com.mycompany.TheEntryPoint</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

How do I load such class into my java app dynamically?

**Update:**

- The jar is loaded as byte stream and does not reside in the file system or URL

Comment: Can you please clarify your last sentence, I believe you accidentally a word.

Comment: @JesusRamos "accidentally a word"? Ironic.

Comment: @millimoose That was the point :)

Comment: @JesusRamos Yah, sorry about that, fixed the grammar already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a [`URLClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#URLClassLoader%28java.net.URL%5B%5D,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29) instead of trying to do this from scratch from a byte stream. You can always write the .jar out to a temporary file and create a URL to that.

The code would look something like:

```
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(
    new URL[] {new URL("file://...")},
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

loader.loadClass("com.mycompany.TheEntryPoint");
```

You can also detect the main class name (or invoke it) automatically using [`JarURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html). (Oracle also has [a tutorial on using this class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/jarclassloader.html).)

Comment: Your JarURLConnection links to java.lang.Thread. You might want to consider it linking to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html.

Comment: @RyanAmos Whoops, clipboard content confusion struck there. Thanks for picking up on it.

Comment: @millimoose I really don't have much of a choice but to read from bytestream, the jar is not located in a file directory or URL

Comment: @xybrek As I said, you could write the byte stream out to a temporary file, and use the URL to that. Unless for some reason you're not allowed to use temporary files, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: @xybrek Well, to get around that fairly inane restriction, you'll probably have to do things "from scratch". Subclass `ClassLoader`, override `findClass()` (see [the docs for `ClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html)), and consult [the source for `URLClassLoader`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/net/URLClassLoader.java?av=f) to see how it reads JAR files - you should be able to reuse or copy some of that.

Comment: @xybrek (Out of curiosity, what's the reason why you can't write out temporary files? Seems like a rather inane restriction to me.)

Comment: @millimoose I'm using Google AppEngine (GAE) so I can write files due to its restricted there (mainly due to the fact that apps built for it are distributed in nature)

Comment: @millimoose Anyway, I am trying out the code in a normal JVM environment first, but I'm getting ClassNotFoundException, although I checked the jar and the class is there. Is there a way to list which classes from the URLClassLoader?

Comment: @xybrek I don't think so. A class path `ClassLoader` should work by going through the classpath entries in order, and trying to find the class in each one - i.e. they don't necessarily analyse their contents before hand. If `URLClassLoader` does that (it'd be a valid optimisation), there definitely isn't any `API` to look at its index of known classes.

Comment: @xybrek If you're getting a `ClassNotFoundException`, check if you can open the JAR file and class file manually using /the URLs that `URLClassLoader` is using. It's entirely possible I made a mistake you're not supposed to use `file://` URLs to point to .jars. You could verify this by looking at the `URLClassLoader` that Java uses as the "default" one - if you fire up a debugger you should be able to see the list of URLs it uses. (The [`URLClassPath ucp` field](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/net/URLClassLoader.java#URLClassLoader.0ucp)