# How can I determine the entry point of Java applet from its JAR file?

Tags: java, japplet

Is there a way to determine the starting point of a java applet given just the jar file? I'm trying to create a website where I can upload an applet's jar file and then play it back with something similar to the following.

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" height="450" width="450">
  <param name="code" value="<? echo $startingClass; ?>" />
  <param name="archive" value="<? echo $jarUrl; ?>" />
  Applet failed to run.
</object>
```

The applet's I've been given do not have correct manifest or jnlp files. I've tried using jar -tvf 'jarfile.jar' to get a list of all of the classes in the jar file, but can't determine which one is the entry point.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds very complicated to me. Roughly I think this is needed:

1. after upload of the jar on the server, you would need a custom class loader to load the jar on your server (see [Load jar dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504120/load-jar-dynamically)).
2. Then you can use Reflection to find applet main class in it,
3. then you would redirect to a JSP where you can generate the needed `<object>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

> .. but can't determine which one is the entry point.

Use something like:

```
if (exampleOfClass instanceof Applet) { // We're good to go!...
```

Comment: How would I go about using the information from the string "pac/kage/ClassName.class" to get a class that I can check the instance of?

Comment: Ah, I can use Class.forName("pac.kage.ClassName") to get the class. Very cool! I'm not able to instantiate an actual object, but Applet.class.isAssignableFrom seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial solution based on the other comments, but I ran into an issue where not all subclasses of applet were being identified ([How can identify Applet subclasses from a Jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579579/why-is-this-main-class-not-a-subclass-of-applet)). The program will print out the classes inside the Jar file that are a subclass of `Applet`. One of those classes (possibly the most-derived class) is the entry point.

```
import java.applet.Applet;

public class JarAppletIdentifier 
{  
  public static void main(String [] args)
    throws Exception
  {
    for(String class_name : args) {
      class_name = class_name.replace(".class", "");

      Class<?> c = Class.forName(class_name);
      if(Applet.class.isAssignableFrom(c))
        System.out.println(class_name);
    }   
  }
}
```

This snippet expects as arguments the list of classes in the jar file.

Using linux, the arguments can be read from the jar file and parsed using

```
// prints out, eg. 
//   pac.kage.Main.class
//   pac.kage.Other.class
//   user.pac.kage.SomeClass.class
jar_classes=$(jar -tf example.jar | 
  grep .class | grep -v "\\$" | grep -v "^\." | sed 's/\//\./g')
```

You can then pass this result into the program with

```
echo $jar_classes | xargs java -classpath "example.jar" JarAppletIdentifier
```