# How can identify Applet subclasses from a Jar file?

Tags: java, reflection, applet, japplet

I have the two following class hierarchy in jar files where the only difference is that `Main` in example2.jar has no package while `Main` in example1.jar is part of the package `user`.

example1.jar

```
// user/Main.java
package user;
import Engine.GameWindow;
public class Main extends GameWindow { }

// Engine/GameWindow.java
package Engine;
import java.applet.Applet;
public abstract class GameWindow extends Applet { }
```

example2.jar

```
// Main.java
import Engine.GameWindow;
public class Main extends GameWindow { }

// Engine/GameWindow.java
package Engine;
import java.applet.Applet;
public abstract class GameWindow extends Applet { }
```

I created this program to determine which classes inside of a jar file are subclasses of Applet.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
public class JarClassIdentifier 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
    throws Exception 
  {
    // example1.jar: args = { "user.Main.class", "Engine.GameWindow.class" }
    // example2.jar: args = { "Main.class", "Engine.GameWindow.class" }
    for(String class_name : args) {
      class_name = class_name.replace(".class", "");

      Class<?> c = Class.forName(class_name);

      if(Applet.class.isAssignableFrom(c))
        System.out.println(class_name);
    }
  }
}
```

For example1.jar, the program correctly prints `user.Main` and `Engine.GameWindow`. Why does example2.jar only print out `Engine.GameWindow`?

Comment: *"Main class is part of the package user"* - Then in that case, shouldn't "Main.class" be "user.Main.class"?

Comment: Please show your actual code around `Class.forName()`. I suspect you're ignoring a useful `ClassNotFoundException`, either because of the package issue @MadProgrammer noted or because you incorrectly capitalized `.class`.

Comment: I updated my question to fix some typos and clarify what I meant. `args` is the the main function arguments and is being provided by parsing the output of `tar -tf example.jar`